# Como posso fazer para aplicar um estilo apenas para um ou outro <p>?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twig, tinymce

Estou com um problema que aparentemente é simples mas por causa da minha falta de experiência estou me ferrando. É o seguinte, eu estou fazendo uma listagem do banco de dados de um texto, e esse texto já vem com as tags `<p></p>` junto. Essas informações foram cadastradas usando o Tinymce e nele tem a opção de colocar midia de fundo, mas essa mídia vem em um `style="background: url('url da imagem')"` e isso vem dentro da minha tag `<p>`. Dai eu preciso fazer uma configuração de estilo com css mas não consigo afetar apenas a tag que contém o style com o background. Eu tentei usar o addClass do jquery e funcionou mas só se eu clicar no `<p>`.

--- HTML ----

```
<p>texto</p>
<p sytle="background: url('exemplo.com')"></p>
<p>outro texto</p>
```

--- Jquery ---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('teste')
     });
});
```

---- CSS ---

```
.teste{
   height: 500px
}
```

Comment: por favor, adicione o código javascript que você tentou

Comment: Já adicionei um pedaço do que eu tentei fazer. O meu problema é que o texto ja vem com as tags direto do banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se percebi bem o problema, mas pareceu-me que tens dificuldades em apanhar um elemento que tenha o `style="background: url('url da imagem')"`, não é?

Tentei reproduzir o teu problema neste [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2c8a18w/1/)

**HTML**

```
<p>texto</p>
<p style="background:yellow">segundo texto</p>
<p>outro texto</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
 if(list[i].style.background == 'yellow')
 {
  alert("sim");
     //Função que quiseres fazer caso tenha aquele estilo
 }
 else
 {
    alert("no");
     //Função que quiseres fazer caso não tenha aquele estilo
 }
}
```

**P.S.** Coloquei uma cor em vez de um url só para efeitos de teste, mas acredito que funcione na mesma, apenas tens que trocar o valor da condição do `if`

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .azul{
    color:blue
    }
    .vermelho{
    color:red
    }
```

```html
<p class='vermelho'>teste</p>
<p class='azul'>teste</p>
```